# Closing a list item dropdown on selecting an item or clicking outside it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have made a dropdown in my react js project with list items in it (Dropdown items are shown by ul and li tags here).

The issue i am facing is that on selecting any item the value in state changes but the dropdown doesn't close not do it closes when i click anywhere outside of it.
Please help me out, here is the working codesandbox url for the same repo

[Check here](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-bash-jv58n)

Also i am sharing the code below .

App.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./dropdown";
import "./dropdown.css";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);

  const selectedValue = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    setValue(value);
  };
  const onSelectItem = () => {
    console.log("12");
    setShowDropdown(false);
  };

  return (
    <section className="shadow-border" id="FlightsForm">
      <div className="top-sec d-flex">
        <div className="left-side">
          <span
            className="custm-dropdown"
            onClick={() => setShowDropdown(true)}
          >
            <span style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", color: "white" }}>
              {value.tripType}
            </span>
            <span className="dropdown-icon"> </span>
            <Dropdown
              selectedValue={selectedValue}
              onSelectItem={onSelectItem}
              showDropdown={showDropdown}
            />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Dropdown.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TripTypeDropdown = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([
    { tripType: "One Way", value: 1 },
    { tripType: "Return", value: 2 },
    { tripType: "Multi- City", value: 3 },
  ]);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState({
    tripType: "One Way",
    value: 1,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    props.selectedValue(selectedItem);
    console.log(selectedItem);
  }, [selectedItem]);

  const selectItemFromList = (index) => {
    const itemSelected = values[index];
    setSelectedItem(itemSelected);
    props.onSelectItem();
  };
  const getActiveClassName = (item) => {
    if (selectedItem) {
      if (item.tripType == selectedItem.tripType) return "active";
      else return "";
    }
  } ;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        className={`dropdown-modal sm-modal ripple trip-type-dropdown`}
        style={{ display: `${props.showDropdown ? "block" : "none"}` }}
      >
        <ul>
          {console.log(values)}
          {values.map((item, index) => (
            <li
              className={getActiveClassName(item)}
              onClick={() => selectItemFromList(index)}
              key={index}
               style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',border:"1px solid black",listStyle:"none"}}
            >
              {item.tripType}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TripTypeDropdown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the propagation of the click event from the list item to the outer span, this is defeating any attempts to toggle the dropdown closed again from the parent.

```
const selectItemFromList = (index) => (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  const itemSelected = values[index];
  setSelectedItem(itemSelected);
  props.onSelectItem();
};

...

<li
  key={index}
  ...
  onClick={selectItemFromList(index)}
  ...
>
  {item.tripType}
</li>
```

To handle outside clicks you attach a React ref to the dropdown div and use an `useEffect` hook to add an `onClick` event listener to the widow object and check that the `onClick`'s event target ***is not*** contained within the dropdown div.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const outsideClickHandler = (e) => {
    if (props.showDropdown && !outsideRef.current?.contains(e.target)) {
      props.onSelectItem(false);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("click", outsideClickHandler);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("click", outsideClickHandler);
}, [props]);

...

<div
  ref={outsideRef}
  ...
>
  ...
</div>
```

## Demo

[image: Edit closing-a-list-item-dropdown-on-selecting-an-item-or-clicking-outside-it]

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop bubbling up of click event from your dropdown component to it's parent span element. On click you need to pass thevent argument and call `stopPropagation` function of event object

Here is the [condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-leakey-cfi32)

Dropdown.js

```
const selectItemFromList = (e,index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

...

<li
     className={getActiveClassName(item)}
     onClick={(e) => selectItemFromList(e,index)}
     key={index}
```

Also added code for outside click.

```
const ref = useRef();

...

useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleDropdownClick);
  }, [ref]);

const handleDropdownClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (ref.current && ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setShowDropdown(true);
    } else {
      setShowDropdown(false);
    }
  };

...

<span
     ref={ref}
     className="custm-dropdown"
     onClick={handleDropdownClick}
 >
```

Comment: thanks but i also want to figure out how to close this dropdown when user clicks anywhere else on the screen

Comment: I am looking into it. You should be able to do it with `useRef` and on body click

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai Hi I tested it in my local it's working both outside click and in drodown